# Have some troubles with borders

Tags: html, css

I'm making a web page for restaurant. Design says, that I need a little line between page selectors. Have already tried something, but thing worked.

It's HTML5 and CSS3.

```css
* {
    margin: 0em;
    padding: 0em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

html {
    background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1526234362653-3b75a0c07438?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1489&q=80) black no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}

h1 {
    color: white;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 5% 0 13%;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: black;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.95);
    border-radius: 10px;
}

a:link {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
    color: white;
}

a:hover {
    line-height: 0 !important;
    transform: scale(1.5) !important;
    transition: all 1s ease !important;
    color: wheat;
}

.menu {
    font-size: 32px;
    width: 75%;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 960px;
}

.left {
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    border-right: solid white;
    padding-right: 25px;
}

.right {
    float: right;
    text-align: left;
    border-left: solid white;
    padding-left: 25px;
}

a {
    list-style-position: inside;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <h1 class="home-header">Restoran</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="left">
            <ul>
                <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Restoran" asp-action="Menu">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Restoran" asp-action="Reservation">Reservation</a></li>
                <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Restoran" asp-action="Deals">Deals</a></li>
                <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Restoran" asp-action="Shop">Shop</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="right">
            <ul>
                <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Restoran" asp-action="Events">Events</a></li>
                <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Restoran" asp-action="Gallery">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Restoran" asp-action="Contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Restoran" asp-action="AboutUs">About Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I hope everything is not so bad :D
Really need this help!

And this is what i would like to have:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pdGH.jpg

Comment: And the trouble is?... what's the problem?

Comment: I can's make these white lines. These are made in PS to show :D

Comment: Like, hr element, yes, but i don`t know how to change it's long

Comment: use a css like `li > a{border-bottom:1px solid #FFF}`

Comment: Nope, nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: ScreenShot]
Added lines (`<hr>`) between your menu selectors

```
<body>
<header>
    <h1 class="home-header">Restoran</h1>
</header>
<div class="menu">
    <div class="left">
        <ul>
            <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Restoran" asp-action="Menu">Menu</a></li><hr>
            <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Restoran" asp-action="Reservation">Reservation</a></li><hr>
            <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Restoran" asp-action="Deals">Deals</a></li><hr>
            <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Restoran" asp-action="Shop">Shop</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="right">
        <ul>
            <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Restoran" asp-action="Events">Events</a></li><hr>
            <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Restoran" asp-action="Gallery">Gallery</a></li><hr>
            <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Restoran" asp-action="Contact">Contact</a></li><hr>
            <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Restoran" asp-action="AboutUs">About Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

For the CSS I suggest you don't use **!important**

A sample [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/datt265/zm5gd6qc/20/)

Comment: Okay, but how can i change its long? Because now its for whole box width

Comment: Through CSS hr { 
width : 50%;
}

Comment: Sorry, but i didn't vote!
Yes, thank you, line appeared, but i need to change its long. It's my main problem. I just tried to copy your solution to mine and only lines appeared. (I don't have 15 rep to vote :D)

Comment: I added a screenshot which shows that <hr> tag is resized

Comment: Yes. It's working. Just something wrong with VS 2019. Tried in VS Code, everything okay. Sorry for your wasted time! Thank you!